# Javascript JSON results throws text is null error

Tags: ajax, json, instagram

I am using ajax to pull photos from instagram. Below is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=" + lat +"&lng=" + lng + "&distance=" + distance + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "",
    success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
             $("#instagram").append("<li><a class='group' title='' href='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url +"'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>");   
        }     

    }
});
```

This works well due to the fact that the anchors title attribute is left blank. I was using `title='" + data.data[i].caption.text + "'` to pull the instagram caption as the anchor title. For the most part, this works, but I often get the following error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null"**

I am assuming this is happening from one of two reasons:
A) no caption at all
B) a caption with characters that will not work as a title.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and also how I can fix this? I tried the following but it throws the same error:

```
if(data.data[i].caption.text != null) { 
     var title = data.data[i].caption.text;
} else {
     var title = "";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A is the case here: caption is null. B would not trigger that error. I  guess the response is not including null fields to optimize on networking. Check for null before using the caption property.

Comment: how would I check for null before using it when that is what I am checking...if the caption is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no caption attached, Instagram does not return that field. Just add another null check.

```
if (data.data[i].caption !=null) {
    if(data.data[i].caption.text != null) { 
       var title = data.data[i].caption.text;
    } 
} else { 
   var title = "";
}
```

Comment: this worked great, thanks. I had no idea that Instagram doesnt return that field if left blank. I assumed it would just return an empty string

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x in data.data) {
    var title_text = '';

    if (data.data[x].caption != null) {
        if (data.data[x].caption.text != null) {
            title_text = data.data[x].caption.text;
        }
    } else {
        title_text = "";
    }

    $("#instagram").append("<a target="_blank" href="' + data.data[x].link + '">" + title_text);
}
```